# How to connect to an instance on a private subnet from an instance on a public subnet with different CIDR range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, subnet

I have a VPC with two CIDR ranges attached:
10.0.0.0/16 and 172.0.0.0/16.

I have created 2 subnets
S1:10.0.0.0/24 and
S2: 172.0.0.0/24.

I also have two route tables with each subnet in it
RT1--->S1
It also has internet gateway attachment

The other route table which is:
RT2--->S2
This route table does not have internet gateway in it.

I have now launched two instances
I1--S1
I2--S2
If I am trying to connect to I2 from I1 I am not able to do it. The ping fails. But this should not happen. Although both the instances have Ip's belonging to different CIDR ranges. It should be able to communicate. What could possibly cause this? Also please tell me a way to setup communication between the two instances?

Comment: Could you double-check and make sure that S1 has a route to S2 in RT1 and S2 has a route to S1 in RT2?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Problem was with security groups. Ports were not enabled properly. Thanks for your comment